# Back Button Takes Me To Wrong View Controller

Tags: swift, segue

I have a storyboard I'm working with that is setup as so:

Login Screen -> Tab Bar Controller - > Navigation Controller - > Screen 1 Segue to Screen 2 Segue to Screen 3.

The first time I login, everything works great.  Screen 1 segues to screen 2, screen 2 segues to screen 3, you can then use the back button to go back to screen 2 and then screen 1.  However, I have a "logout" function (code below, although I don't think this is relevant to my issue) and after I "logout", it takes me to the Login Screen (first screen in the sequence above).  When I then login again, navigate to Screen 2 or Screen 3, pressing the back button from the segue takes me all the way back to the login screen as opposed to the prior Screen 1 or Screen 2.

```
@objc func logOut(){
    let homeView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeView, animated: true)
    homeView.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

Comment: It sounds like to me that you should be unwinding back to the login page rather than directing the user there as according to the view hierarchy, the back button wants to return to the last view, which would be `Screen 2` or `Screen 3`.

Comment: Aaron - that's the point.  It is returning to the login screen. I want it to go to Screen 2 or Screen 1 per normal functionality.

Comment: I just said that. It's because you're disrupting the navigation stack which is causing it to incorrectly return. Have a look at rewriting your logout code by not instantiating the Login screen again and unwinding the segue.

Comment: aaron - I will look into that but remember, I am segueing to screen 2 from screen 1, then pressing back, and it takes me to Login.  that makes zero sense as Login is not the last view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that instantiating the `LoginViewController` again is the best practice, since you already have it in you navigation stack. I would recommend doing something like this:

```
@objc func logOut(){
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

This will remove all the view controllers from the navigtion stack, and present you with a root view controller (`LoginViewController`)

Comment: the login view controller is not the root view controller, that's the issue.  Remember, the Login View Controller is before the navigation controller.

Comment: ah, I've mised that, ok, then in that case shouldn't adding the  `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` to your existing logout code solve your problem?

Comment: no, because when I press Logout, I want to return to the Login Screen, which is not the root view controller of the navigation controller (Screen 1 is).

Answer (score 0):

Updated for anyone who is curious.  The pushViewController option was the issue.  If i just use "present", I no longer have this issue.  Here is my updated logout code:

```
@objc func logOut(){
    let homeView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.present(homeView, animated: true)
    homeView.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

}